# Peculiar error downloading keys/files from S3 bucket - [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using a python script to get all the files in an S3 bucket. The relevant code snippet is as follow:

```
        print ("Downloading files...")
        for f in files:
            cwd=os.getcwd()
            fname=cwd+"/"
            fname = fname+f.name
            dir = os.path.dirname(fname)
            if not os.path.exists(dir): 
                    print dir
                    os.makedirs(dir)
            try:
                f.get_contents_to_filename(fname)
            except OSError,e:
                print e
```

When I do this on a bucket which is used to store log files, I get this error on all the folders in that bucket. E.g. for the logs folder here:

```
Downloading files...
/private/tmp/test/logs
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/test/logs/
```

Despite the error, all the directories and files get downloaded.

Why does that happen? It does not happen on any other buckets, except for this bucket where log files from other buckets are sent to. Or is it something to do with the code? Or permissions on the bucket. It has the default permissions, nothing that I have changed.

Comment: Basically, user, under which you are running this script on your machine, doesn't have permissions to write to directory /private/tmp/test/logs/. You need to check permissions (or owner) for that dir.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Because, like I said, it works fine with other s3 buckets which have folders, when I try and download them into the same directory.

Only this one bucket seems to have this problem and it's a bucket specifically used for dumping log files.

Comment: Well, you can easely check it, by running ```result = f.get_contents_as_string()``` and after actual download saving contents to file in your system ```with open(fname, 'w') as fd: fd.write(result)```, and checking, which operation is raising Exception.

Comment: you should add that as an answer. I think I figured out what the problem was.

I was trying to write a directory, when I should have been skipping it after I created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @pavel_form's suggestion, I figured out the problem. I was trying to write a directory as a file. Fixed the code using this block, specifically checking if the basename is empty:

```
            if (not os.path.basename(fname)==""):
                try:
                    f.get_contents_to_filename(fname)
                except OSError,e:
                    print e
```